# How to handle polymorphic type for both value and function?

Tags: flowtype

Consider the following type:

```
declare class Test<T> {
  static of(value: T): Test<T>;
  map<U>(fn: (value:T) => U): Test<U>;
}
```

Now for function `ap`, `T` is a `function` and it works like this:

```
Test.of(x => x * 2)
    .ap(Test.of(5))
    .map(console.log) // Output(number): 10

Test.of(x => `${x * 2}!`)
    .ap(Test.of(5))
    .map(console.log) // Output(string): 10!
```

So, to properly type check `ap` I need to do `ap(Test<[get type of x]>): [type of output of T]`

I tried `Test<I, O>`, where `I` is optional for values. But, it adds a lots of unnecessary thing to other functions. Is there any better way to solve this?

**Note:** I'm trying to write type definition for [data.task](http://docs.folktalejs.org/en/master/api/data/task/Task.html#ap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one! The `ap()` method can't be called on an instance of `Test<T>` for all `T`'s, but only when `T` is a function that takes at most one argument.

So what you really need is something that is still TODO for Flow. It would look like this:

```
declare class Test<T> {
  static of(value: T): Test<T>;
  map<U>(fn: (value:T) => U): Test<U>;
  ap<I,O>(this: Test<(in: I) => O>, test: Test<I>): Test<O>;
}
```

It declares that `this` must be a `Test<T>` where `T` is a function that takes `I`. [Here's a GitHub issue about it](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/452).

In the meantime, you could do a first order approximation. It would look like this:

```
declare class Test<T> {
  static of<I, O>(fn: (in: I) => O): FuncTest<I, O>;
  static of(value: T): Test<T>;

  map<U>(fn: (value:T) => U): Test<U>;
}

declare class FuncTest<I, O> extends Test<(in: I) => O> {
  ap(x: Test<I>): Test<O>;
}

Test.of(x => x * 2)
    .ap(Test.of(5))
    .map(x => (x: number)) // no error

Test.of(x => `${x * 2}!`)
    .ap(Test.of(5))
    .map(x => (x: string)) // no error
```

[Try this example on flowtype.org/try](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVATApgYxgQwCcsw98BncsAFS3IBcAeagPjAG9UwwH96BLHGDhRGASQA0YAPIsAFFAB2ALjBz+KsGICUYALxtp21QDEAropy0G4qbIDcXHvT6DhUOQDd8MM1lXUxjR0TKyO3E4AtvgADowAqvJKql4+fsqB+mzxQdZMiY4AvujYZMSkBJRg5pZ5tjJsWAAe9FiKGFR16po6WQ0cTrFyTQEh4iy5Yw6oxah5AHQiw31NyGAATNpO3PNDC0sArNpb3DvRMcsGaiNgimaRAEZYhMfo+x6rVwAGACTsq+B1oUAIRfE6nXYXd5yI7gs5DT5sYaqBiEDQAc2OQA)

The downside of this approach is that `ap()` returns `Test<O>`, even if `O` is a function. So you can't call `ap()` twice.

```
Test.of(x => Test.of(y => x * y))
  .ap(Test.of(5))
  .map(x => (x: Test<(y: number) => number>)); // This is fine

Test.of(x => Test.of(y => x * y))
  .ap(Test.of(5))
  .ap(Test.of(2)) // This is an error :(
```